# What are the internet standards for the CNAME record?

Tags: domain-name-system, internet, cname-record

I'd like to know what internet standard defines the CNAME

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt) described the CNAME record, originally. There may be some RFCs that obselete it, but I'm not sure off the top of my head.

Comment: To see which (DNS) RFCs update or obsolete others, see http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2010/05/24/436/

Answer (score 5):

Next time, have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) first, it is in the first sentence after the toc there.

Comment: Also a quick Google search for "CNAME RFC" would have helped a lot.

Comment: Should also point out (in case folks don't know) that the IETF's (Internet Engineering Task Force) RFC system define many of the internet standards, usually looking for "thing rfc" will turn up the formal specification for that thing.